# JSON parsing not working with JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, sockets

I have a JSON question.

The following code is where the error occurs. I have verified the result string is the following.

```
{"name":"test", "num1":1.0, "num2":2.0}
```

and this is the code.

```
byte[] raw = new byte[1536];

try{

   DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( raw, raw.length ); 
   mSocket.receive( packet ); //Multicast Socket declared in another part of the program
   String result = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
   JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
   String name = jObj.getString("name");
}
catch (JSONException e){

}
catch(Exception eX){

}
```

However I get a JSONException with the following error.

No value for name.

Is there something wrong with my JSON syntax?

Thanks,

[image: This is what the string shows me]

[image: This is what the json object shows me]

Comment: No, it looks fine. You might verify that it really is all you're getting back by pointing your browser to the url.

Comment: are you sure your result contain {"name":"test", "num1":1.0, "num2":2.0} ??

Comment: Try using Log to get the exact string from the service and post that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue with the encoding. Have you tried specifying UTF-8

```
String response = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength(), "UTF-8");
```

I'm not sure what the issue could be. The rest of your code looks correct.

Comment: In logcat I am seeing the following. 06-18 11:50:52.550: I/result string info(21713): {??"??n??a??m??e??"??:??"??t??e??s??t??"??,??"??n??u??m??1??"??:??1??.??0??,??"??n??u??m??2??"??:??2??.??0??} I think you are right about the encoding. However, I used the "UTF-8" parameter and I still get the same string.

Comment: Yes it was an encoding error on the server side. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = "{\"name\":\"test\", \"num1\":1.0, \"num2\":2.0}";
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(result);
System.out.println(data.getString("name"));
System.out.println(data.get("num1"));
System.out.println(data.get("num2"));
```